# Python, XML parsing, and Elementtree

Tags: python, xml, blender, elementtree

What am I screwing up here?

I can't get this to return any results. I'm sure I'm doing something stupid. I'm not a programmer and this is driving me crazy. Trying to learn but after about 8 hours I'm frazzled.

**Here is a sample of my XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

-<MyObjectBuilder_Sector xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<!-- Saved '2014-08-23T15:28:07.8585220-05:00' with SEToolbox version '1.44.14.2' -->


-<Position>

<X>0</X>

<Y>0</Y>

<Z>0</Z>

</Position>


-<SectorEvents>


-<Events>


-<MyObjectBuilder_GlobalEventBase>


-<DefinitionId>

<TypeId>MyObjectBuilder_GlobalEventDefinition</TypeId>

<SubtypeId>SpawnCargoShip</SubtypeId>

</DefinitionId>

<Enabled>false</Enabled>

<ActivationTimeMs>401522</ActivationTimeMs>

</MyObjectBuilder_GlobalEventBase>

</Events>

</SectorEvents>

<AppVersion>1044014</AppVersion>


-<SectorObjects>


-<MyObjectBuilder_EntityBase xsi:type="MyObjectBuilder_VoxelMap">

<EntityId>72248529206701361</EntityId>

<PersistentFlags>CastShadows InScene</PersistentFlags>


-<PositionAndOrientation>

<Position z="-466" y="-8987" x="-95"/>

<Forward z="-1" y="0" x="0"/>

<Up z="0" y="1" x="0"/>

</PositionAndOrientation>

<Filename>BaseAsteroid.vox</Filename>

</MyObjectBuilder_EntityBase>


-<MyObjectBuilder_EntityBase xsi:type="MyObjectBuilder_VoxelMap">

<EntityId>72151252176979970</EntityId>

<PersistentFlags>CastShadows InScene</PersistentFlags>


-<PositionAndOrientation>

<Position z="-11301.9033" y="-1183.70569" x="-2126.84"/>

<Forward z="-1" y="0" x="0"/>

<Up z="0" y="1" x="0"/>

</PositionAndOrientation>

<Filename>asteroid0.vox</Filename>

</MyObjectBuilder_EntityBase>


-<MyObjectBuilder_EntityBase xsi:type="MyObjectBuilder_VoxelMap">

<EntityId>72108197145016458</EntityId>

<PersistentFlags>CastShadows InScene</PersistentFlags>


-<PositionAndOrientation>

<Position z="355.7873" y="18738.05" x="1064.912"/>

<Forward z="-1" y="0" x="0"/>

<Up z="0" y="1" x="0"/>

</PositionAndOrientation>

<Filename>asteroid1.vox</Filename>

</MyObjectBuilder_EntityBase>
```

**Here is my code, it just never finds anything...:(**

```
from xml.etree import cElementTree as ElementTree

    ElementTree.register_namespace('xsi', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLScheme-instance')
    namespace = {'xsi': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLScheme-instance'} 

    xmlPath = 'e:\\test.xml'
    xmlRoot = ElementTree.parse(xmlPath).getroot()

    #why this no return anything
    results = xmlRoot.findall(".//SectorObjects/MyObjectBuilder_EntityBase[@xsi:type='MyObjectBuilder_VoxelMap']", namespaces=namespace)
    print(results)
```

Comment: That isn't valid XML. You're either going to get an error, or a root with nothing in it. Try pasting it into any XML validator online like [this one](http://www.xmlvalidation.com/) and it'll explain it to you.

Comment: (And of course an empty tree will return nothing for any `findall`.)

Comment: That's just a tiny part of the XML. Trying to upload it now, its about 5MB. Couldn't get stackoverflow to not screw it up. The tree is not empty. if I findall for ".//SectorObjects/" I get plenty.

Comment: Keeps timing out on that validator....let me try again.

Comment: You need to give us an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that actually demonstrates your problem in something small enough to show us and let us test if you want anyone to debug it. Meanwhile, that validator is just the first thing that came up in a quick google. There are hundreds of them online and downloadable for your system; you don't have to use that one.

Comment: Yeah, I ran it through another one and it says its fine. Let me just through up a link to the actual XML. 5 minutes.

Comment: Also, you can find nice XML tools that run online or on your system that let you test and debug XPath queries. Etree doesn't support all of XPath, so just because a full XPath tool works doesn't mean Etree will… but if such a tool _doesn't_ work, you know your problem isn't with Etree, and an XPath debugger will help you fix it.

Comment: You're not getting errors on those stray `-` character outside the root?

Comment: those stray - were just me not knowing how to get the sample uploaded....I updated it with a link.

Comment: Thanks for the help but ok assume I want to only get the MyObjectBuilders_EntityBase that have the xsi:type=MyObjectBuilder_voxelMap? I want to pull the Filename and position elements out into a variable. I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is 'What am I screwing up here?' First of all your XML itself has issues and seems you cannot get it to paste here right. I did few things to make it workable.

1) Added lines below since they were not there in the XML:

```
</SectorObjects>
</MyObjectBuilder_Sector>
```

2) The findall function doesn't take a named argument 'namespaces' and the xsi part also gave an error (SyntaxError: prefix 'xsi' not found in prefix map). So I changed the call to:

```
results = xmlRoot.findall(".//SectorObjects/MyObjectBuilder_EntityBase")
```

When I ran the code with above changes, I got this output below:

```
[<Element 'MyObjectBuilder_EntityBase' at 0x025028A8>, <Element 'MyObjectBuilder_EntityBase' at 0x02502CC8>, <Element 'MyObjectBuilder_EntityBase' at 0x02502E18>]
```

If you want to do more with these like getting the value of EntityId, you can do this:

```
results = xmlRoot.findall(".//SectorObjects/MyObjectBuilder_EntityBase")
try:
    for result in results:
        print result.find('EntityId').text
except AttributeError as aE:
    print str(aE)
```

Output:

```
72248529206701361
72151252176979970
72108197145016458
```